# Qt Undo/Redo implementation, can’t connect to a button

Tags: c++, qt, undo-redo

I post the question also in the Qt Forum, [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/52572/)

I am trying to implement an undo and redo commands in my application. I have a QTreeWidget and I’d like to let the user undo and redo an action (ex. change a value in a QTreeWidgetItem columns in the QTreeWidget and undo/redo it).

Here part of my code:

class A.h

```
    class A : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(...);
    ~A();

    ChangeValueTreeCommand      *commands;
    QUndoStack                  *undoStack;
    QPushButton                 *undoBtn;
    QPushButton                 *redoBtn;
    QString                      newValue;

    void changeItem(QTreeWidgetItem* treeWidgetItemChanged, int col);
};
```

class A.cpp

```
A::A(...){
undoStack = new QUndoStack(this);
}

void A::changeItem(QTreeWidgetItem* treeWidgetItemChanged, int col){

     ....
    commands = new ChangeValueTreeCommand(treeWidgetItemChanged, col, newValue);
    connect(undoBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), commands, SLOT(undo()));
    undoStack->push(commands);

}
```

class Commands.h

```
    #ifndef COMMANDS_H
#define COMMANDS_H

#include <QApplication>

#include <QUndoCommand>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>


class ChangeValueTreeCommand : public QUndoCommand
{
public:
    explicit ChangeValueTreeCommand(QTreeWidgetItem* treeWI = NULL, int c = 0, const QString changedV = "");
    ~ChangeValueTreeCommand();

    QTreeWidgetItem* treeWItem;
    const QString    changedValue;
    int col;

public slots:

    void undo();
    void redo();
};


#endif // COMMANDS_H
```

class Commands.cpp

```
    #include "Commands.h"

ChangeValueTreeCommand::ChangeValueTreeCommand(QTreeWidgetItem* treeWI, int c, const QString changedV)
        : treeWItem(treeWI), col(c), changedValue(changedV)

{}

ChangeValueTreeCommand::~ChangeValueTreeCommand(){}

void ChangeValueTreeCommand::undo()
{
    const QString oldValue = treeWItem->text(col);
    treeWItem->setText(col, oldValue);
}

void ChangeValueTreeCommand::redo()
{
    treeWItem->setText(col, changedValue);
}
```

The problem is that when the user changes the value in the QTreeWidgetItem, it automatically appears the previous value. Moreover, I would like to connect the undo and redo functions to two buttons, but the compiler says that

> 1543: error: C2664: ‘QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)‘ÿ: cannot convert parameter 3 from ‘ChangeValueTreeCommand *’ to ‘const QObject *’
>   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Can someone help me? Thx

Comment: You cannot establish connection with the object that is not a `QObject` -your `ChangeValueTreeCommand` is a `QUndoCommand`.

Comment: yes, I understood that and I don't know how can I connect the Undo PushButton to the undo() function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `undo` and `redo` Buttons should call `undoStack->undo()` / `undoStack->redo()`. This will move the stack pointer and will call the `undo`/`redo` function of the current command.

See the Qt Documentation for a detailed Explanation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qundostack.html#undo

Escpecially this part:

> New commands are pushed on the stack using push(). Commands can be
>   undone and redone using undo() and redo(), or by triggering the
>   actions returned by createUndoAction() and createRedoAction().
>
> QUndoStack keeps track of the current command. This is the command
>   which will be executed by the next call to redo(). The index of this
>   command is returned by index(). The state of the edited object can be
>   rolled forward or back using setIndex(). If the top-most command on
>   the stack has already been redone, index() is equal to count().